# Mithriljs add onkeydown event when component is created

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I am trying to initialize an `onkeydown` event when a component is created:

```
var KeyboardComponent = {
     parse: function(e){
       console.log("pressed: " + e.key);
     },
     view: function() {
        return m("div.keyboard-container", {onkeydown: (e) => this.parse(e)});
     }
};

m.mount(document.body, KeyboardComponent);
```

But when I type anything, no event is printed in the console. I'm not sure how the event be defined, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `m('input')` inside the `div` and typing in the input box.  It works for me.

```js
var KeyboardComponent = {
     parse: function(e){
       console.log("pressed: " + e.key);
     },
     view: function() {
        return m("div.keyboard-container", {
            onkeydown: (e) => this.parse(e)
        }, m('input'));
     }
};

m.mount(document.body, KeyboardComponent);
```